# connect from pycharm to GCE in GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, pycharm

I want to connect to a GCE instance of GCP.

I have the following information in my .ssh/config file:

```
Host NGINX
    HostName HOGE
    IdentityFile /Users/xxx/.ssh/google_compute_engine
    CheckHostIP no
    HashKnownHosts no
    HostKeyAlias compute.〇〇〇
    IdentitiesOnly yes
    StrictHostKeyChecking yes
    UserKnownHostsFile /Users/xxx/.ssh/google_compute_known_hosts
    ProxyCommand /Users/xxx/.config/gcloud/virtenv/bin/python3 /Users/xxx/google-cloud-sdk/lib/gcloud.py compute start-iap-tunnel nginx-workout %p --listen-on-stdin --project=△△△ --zone=us-central1-a --verbosity=warning
    ProxyUseFdpass=no
```

I am able to use this information to connect to a remote instance by specifying the Host in VSCode, but I would like to achieve the same connection in Pycharm.
The instance I am trying to connect to does not have an external IP address, I am thinking that it must be connected in the same way as VSCode.
Can you please provide me with specific settings and steps to follow in Pycharm to make this connection?

With the above configuration, I was able to connect using the ssh NGING command. Now we just need to connect Pycharm...

Additional information:

Pycharm version: PyCharm 2022.3.2 (Professional Edition)
Google Cloud SDK version: Google Cloud SDK 418.0.0
OS of the instance and type of SSH server being used: CentOS